# Make an http Request

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am totally new to xcode. I want to display some text in Detail View. On clicking that link, it should be directed to that link in detail View itself. I need to make an http request for this. Can someone guide me through this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use NSUrlConnection which is built in library of iOS and another is ASIHTTP a third party library. google both of them and see some tutorials.